# Simple HTML DOM Parser - Pass variable to URL via form

Tags: php, forms, parsing, dom

I am trying to build a script to make work easier. I am very new to PHP so please bear with me. I hope someone will be able to assist me.

Basically i have simple html dom parser, and what i need it do is add a word/s to end of a url string.

This is what i have so far:

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$SNBS_URL = "http://www.facebook.com/". $clientid
$clientid = $_GET["clientid"];
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html($SNBS_URL);
// find all div tags with id=gbar
foreach($html->find('div#foot') as $e)
echo $e->innertext . '<br>';
?>

 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="extract_html.php">
  Client ID
 <input name="clientid" type="text" id="clientid" value="enter id" />
 </label>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
```

I have used facebook url as a test. I need the form to submit a string to the end of the url and get the html dom parser to parse the final url:

www.facebook.com/ + form submitted keyword

So once submit button is pressed on the web page, the html dom parser will parse www.facebook.com/keyword.entered.

I am sorry if i was very hard to understand, and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
$SNBS_URL = "http://www.facebook.com/". $clientid
$clientid = $_GET["clientid"];
```

should be:

```
$clientid = $_GET["clientid"];
$SNBS_URL = "http://www.facebook.com/". $clientid
```